# duplicate entries in OpenType coverage table

Tags: opentype

Some fonts have duplicate entries in an OpenType coverage table.  For example, if I decode the [Roboto-Regular.ttf](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) using `ttx`, I find the following as part of the `GDEF` table:

```
<MarkGlyphSetsDef>
  <MarkSetTableFormat value="1"/>
  <!-- MarkSetCount=2 -->
  <Coverage index="0">
    <Glyph value="gravecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="gravecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="acutecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="acutecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="tildecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="tildecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="hookabovecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="hookabovecomb"/>
    <Glyph value="uni030F"/>
    <Glyph value="uni030F"/>
    <Glyph value="uni0483"/>
    <Glyph value="uni0484"/>
    <Glyph value="uni0485"/>
    <Glyph value="uni0486"/>
  </Coverage>
  <Coverage index="1">
    <Glyph value="cedilla"/>
    <Glyph value="ogonek"/>
    <Glyph value="dotbelowcomb"/>
    <Glyph value="dotbelowcomb"/>
    <Glyph value="uniF6C3"/>
  </Coverage>
</MarkGlyphSetsDef>
```

Are these valid coverage tables, or is this a bug in the Roboto font files?  Since the font is widely used, I assume that the format must be accepted by font renderers.  In practice, will `gravecomb` have coverage index `0` or `1`?

Comment: Pretty sure you want to ask this over on https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/issues rather than here. This isn't really a programming question and more a highly-project-specific question best asked the people who actually _run_ that project.